# Project Euler task #8 in c++, code returns wrong answer for subtle reason

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I am working through the Project Euler problems and I have reached a dead end early - I am almost certain my code is correct and yet my answer is not accepted as correct.

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My approach is simple - this is my first go at the problem without any optimization, just to see if I can solve it at all:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> // atol ASCII to Integer function


int main(){

std::string digits =    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934";
            digits +=   "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843";
            digits +=   "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511";
            digits +=   "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557";
            digits +=   "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113";
            digits +=   "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749";
            digits +=   "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866";
            digits +=   "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776";
            digits +=   "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243";
            digits +=   "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397";
            digits +=   "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482";
            digits +=   "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474";
            digits +=   "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881";
            digits +=   "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586";
            digits +=   "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042";
            digits +=   "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408";
            digits +=   "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188";
            digits +=   "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606";
            digits +=   "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725";
            digits +=   "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    long product = 1;
    long temp = 1;

    for(int i = 12; i < digits.length(); i++){

        for(int j = 0; j<13; j++){

            temp = temp*atoi(digits.substr(i-j,1).c_str());
        }

        if(temp > product){
            product = temp;
            std::cout << "index: " << (i-12) << " Product: " << product << "\n";
        }

        temp = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This returns the following answers:

```
index: 0 Product: 5000940
index: 16 Product: 9797760
index: 19 Product: 13063680
index: 21 Product: 25401600
index: 22 Product: 50803200
index: 23 Product: 71124480
index: 24 Product: 284497920
index: 25 Product: 568995840
index: 40 Product: 1020366720
index: 41 Product: 1632586752
index: 43 Product: 2040733440
index: 503 Product: 2091059712
```

And so, of course, I submit this last number to the P.E. site, but it is rejected.

I've done the very obvious sanity checking (Do the 13 digits at index 503 actually produce 2091059712?) and yes, they do, so I don't have something subtle where it does the index wrong and only multiplies 12 numbers (or 14) rather than the correct 13.

SO... what could possibly make my code return the wrong number? Do I accidentally multiply by an extra zero without noticing? I've looked at this for an hour now and it's time to get other eyes on my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems 9<sup>13</sup> does not fit into `long` at your platform.

You may replace `long` with `long long int` or some other wider integer.

[live example](http://ideone.com/ZtmROO) gives following output

```
index: 0 Product: 5000940
index: 16 Product: 9797760
index: 19 Product: 13063680
index: 21 Product: 25401600
index: 22 Product: 50803200
index: 23 Product: 71124480
index: 24 Product: 284497920
index: 25 Product: 568995840
index: 40 Product: 1020366720
index: 41 Product: 1632586752
index: 43 Product: 2040733440
index: 88 Product: 2972712960
index: 195 Product: 6270566400
index: 196 Product: 14108774400
index: 197 Product: 23514624000
```

Not making such mistakes is exactly what project euler want to teach you.

Comment: So it might be as simple as an integer overflow? God Damn. I'm going to go back and check if that solves it for me. EDIT: Yup, I get your list too when I change it to long long. Thank you. EDITEDIT: Would accept answer but there appears to be a time limit. It'll happen when I get back to it.